# Continuous functions in a topology

Tags: calculus, general-topology, continuity

The projection function $f : R_{usual}^2 \rightarrow R_{usual}$ given by f(x, y) = x is continuous. Can someone please provide a proof to this, in general when you need to show a function is continuous in a topology how do we show that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick  proof: it's continuous as a map of metric spaces, because 
$$
d(f(p_1), f( p_2)) \le d(p_1, p_2)
$$
and since the usual topology on each space is the one inherited form its metric space structure, this suffices.

In general: you pick an arbitrary open set $U$ in the codomain, let $V = f^{-1}(U)$, and then try to prove, using anything you know, that $V$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

You can also show this pretty easily by showing that slices of the form $f^{-1}(U)$ are open in $R^2$, where $U$ is an open interval. That is, show that sets of the form $(a,b)\times(-\infty,\infty)$ are open. This proof is nice because leads you to the definition of the product topology on arbitrary spaces.